# Raspberry Pi 2 model B with sim800 and PIR to detect motion

Tags: pi-2

I am working in the project that idea is to detect the motion using PIR and picamera. will send email alert to include with capture of the movement and SMS  in the same time.
the component I plan to use is raspberry pi 2 model B desktop 900Mhz 1GB with power adaptor, sim800 ,PIR, pi camera module v2 8 mpixel,1080p.

my question is ...are these devices compatible to work with the raspberry pi.

Comment: Have you already done your own research?

Comment: yes I did . but I get confuse to select the required device to be work with raspberry pi as it is my first try.

Answer (score 0):

yes I use this components (3B+, Cam v2, SIM800, PIR and others) too and they do work together without problems. A question of software as usual...

Regards,
Jorg

Comment: thank you for the fast replay.you mean that you are using raspberry pi 3 module b instead of using raspberry pi 3 module b+. is it the same configuration when use with sim800?

Comment: RPI 3B and RPI 3B+ have the same cofiguration for the GSM/GPRS/GPS-Board

Comment: sorry I mean rpi2 with rpi3